# How to find all combinations of 3 dataframes and return them as list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, combinations

Let´s say I have 3 dataframes. Each dataframe has strings in it and I want to find all possible combinations of those 3 dataframes and output them as list. I searched stackoverflow for a while, tried lot of codes, but non of them worked. I tried importing intertools, combinations etc, but still got wrong output or non at all.

```
def combinator(names,cities,streets) #for example
```

In my last attemp I tried to combine only names with cities with this code :

```
names.merge(cities, how = 'cross')
names['key'] = 1
cities['key'] = 1
combined = pd.merge(names,cities,on='key').drop('key', axis = 1)
```

But only got all names copied. The goal is to find all possible combinations of names, cities and streets and return them in one list. Thanks for all suggestions.

Input dataframes

[image: example input]

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your input data and your expected output?

Comment: So do you have 3 different dataframes? What are the names of their columns?

Comment: ```pd.merge(df1['name'], df2['city'], how='cross').merge(df3['street'], how='cross').to_numpy()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, bind_cols, expand, nesting
>>> 
>>> df1 = tibble(
...     name=["John", "Nick", "Eric"], job=["engineer", "architect", "deisgner"]
... )
>>> df2 = tibble(
...     city=["London", "Montresor", "Esslingen"],
...     bigness=["captical", "villege", "town"],
... )
>>> df3 = tibble(
...     street=["street1", "street2", "street3"],
...     population=["high", "low", "average"],
... )
>>> 
>>> df = bind_cols(df1, df2, df3)
>>> df >> expand(
...     nesting(f.name, f.job),
...     nesting(f.city, f.bigness),
...     nesting(f.street, f.population),
... )
       name        job       city   bigness   street population
   <object>   <object>   <object>  <object> <object>   <object>
0      John   engineer     London  captical  street1       high
1      John   engineer     London  captical  street2        low
2      John   engineer     London  captical  street3    average
3      John   engineer  Montresor   villege  street1       high
4      John   engineer  Montresor   villege  street2        low
5      John   engineer  Montresor   villege  street3    average
6      John   engineer  Esslingen      town  street1       high
7      John   engineer  Esslingen      town  street2        low
8      John   engineer  Esslingen      town  street3    average
9      Nick  architect     London  captical  street1       high
10     Nick  architect     London  captical  street2        low
11     Nick  architect     London  captical  street3    average
12     Nick  architect  Montresor   villege  street1       high
13     Nick  architect  Montresor   villege  street2        low
14     Nick  architect  Montresor   villege  street3    average
15     Nick  architect  Esslingen      town  street1       high
16     Nick  architect  Esslingen      town  street2        low
17     Nick  architect  Esslingen      town  street3    average
18     Eric   deisgner     London  captical  street1       high
19     Eric   deisgner     London  captical  street2        low
20     Eric   deisgner     London  captical  street3    average
21     Eric   deisgner  Montresor   villege  street1       high
22     Eric   deisgner  Montresor   villege  street2        low
23     Eric   deisgner  Montresor   villege  street3    average
24     Eric   deisgner  Esslingen      town  street1       high
25     Eric   deisgner  Esslingen      town  street2        low
26     Eric   deisgner  Esslingen      town  street3    average
```

I am the author of [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), a package that implements the Grammar of Data Manipulation in python, with pandas and modin as backend.